# In Scala, is there an equivalent of Haskell's "fromListWith" for Map?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, there is a function called [fromListWith](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Map.html#15) which can generate a Map from a function (used to merge values with the same key) and a list:

```
fromListWith :: Ord k => (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map k a
```

The following expression will be evaluated to `true`:

```
fromListWith (++) [(5,"a"), (5,"b"), (3,"b"), (3,"a"), (5,"a")] == fromList [(3, "ab"), (5, "aba")]
```

In Scala, there is a similar function called `toMap` on `List` objects , which can also convert a list to a Map, but it can't have a parameter of function to deal with duplicated keys.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apart from using `scalaz` you could also define one yourself:

```
implicit class ListToMapWith[K, V](list: List[(K, V)]) {
  def toMapWith(op: (V, V) => V) = 
    list groupBy (_._1) mapValues (_ map (_._2) reduce op)
}
```

Here is a usage example:

```
scala> val testList = List((5,"a"), (5,"b"), (3,"b"), (3,"a"), (5,"a"))
scala> testList toMapWith (_ + _)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(5 -> aba, 3 -> ba)
```

Comment: Was about to write something similar. +1 for teaching me that `mapValues` exists.

Comment: Note that `mapValues` returns a view which will recalculate the value on every access, which may not be desirable in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The stdlib doesn't have such a feature, however, there is a port of `Data.Map` available in `scalaz` that [does have](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Map.scala#L1114) this function available.